# Why are we losing one degree of freedom in this $\chi^2$ variable?

Tags: statistics

If I define a $\chi^2$ variable from:

$$\chi^2(k) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} X_i^2$$

with $X_i$ k identical independent normal random variables,
I have a distribution with k degrees of freedom.

But the definition:

$$\chi^2(k) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} (X_i-\bar{X})^2$$

with $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} X_i$ has only (k-1) dof.

Where am I losing one dof? Is it by fixing one of the moments of the distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly it is because you fix $\bar{X}$. Since $\bar{X}$ is fixed, if you know the value of $k-1$ of the random variables $X_i, i=1,\ldots, k$ the value of the remaining $k-th$ random variable can be determined.